# SQL tables, two table to reference one column in thirds table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

[image]

I have two kinds of users : Person and Company.

I want to save their password in one table.

How can I connect these two tables with Password? Using sql server (MSSQL)?

Or maybe there are other ways to do it?

I dont want to keep hashedPass in Person or Company tables because I want keep any password changes that user have made.

Comment: are you asking what foreign key you should use?

Comment: I am asking how to make it. Are there many types of foreign key?

Comment: The weird part is what is the login field?

Comment: I would suggest you not use the column name "id" in your tables. It is painful to work with because a certain id changes names based on which table it is in. Since it is a property it should remain the same in every table. So you you have PersonID, PasswordID and CompanyID.

Comment: I don't understand your last bit "I dont want to keep hashedPass in Person or Company tables because I want keep any password changes that user have made."  A user and company will not have the same synched password, as a company can have multiple users.  Maybe I'm just not understanding.

Comment: What does `ID` in password correlate too?  Is it its own ID? Or an ID of ***either*** `user` or `company`?  How are you tracking this dependency?  It seems like you're adding a lot of complication.  I would argue that companies shouldn't have their own passwords, users should be associated to companies and permissions for a user within a company should be managed.

Comment: @Kritner yes Id is either user or company and I must do that, because there are no connection between user and company at all

Comment: @SeanLange thats great suggestion!

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it will be Email, and it will work the same as password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a superclass table for all users, and put the password in there (as well as any other attributes that are shared among all users). Then make the Person and Company tables subclasses of the user table.

EDIT: if you need a third type of user, (say Applications - for software applications that need to logon), add another table for that user type as a third subclass.

[image]

Comment: Is it kind of one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Yes, although technically, it's a `1 <=> 0/1` (one-to-zero or one), relationship.

Comment: can you give any links or a good search keyword so I can find and learn about that strange relationship?

Comment: Try `one to zero or one`, or `database Subclass`. Here's a link http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=subclass.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going in the wrong direction.  Put a `PasswordId` in each table where you want a password:

```
create table Person (
    . . .
    PasswordId int references Passwords(PasswordId)
);

. . .

create table Passwords (
    PasswordId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    . . .
);
```

Then remove the `userId` from the `Passwords` table.

Comment: I said I dont want that, becasue I can't keep track of changed password with that 'direction'

Comment: @mister_giga there isnt any reason you cant keep track of changed password with this aproach. And Gordon have a good point here, you are trying assign a property `user_id` to entity `Password` and that isnt natural.  The `Password` is an `User` property.

Comment: Gordon why you have a Yeti (or a ghost?) in your avatar?

Comment: @mister_giga If you want keep the historic password, maybe is better add a separated table for that.

Comment: Person must not hold key for Password, it should be vice versa, because it will be one two many relationship. and so Person may have many passwords and the password with highest 'createDate' value will be the current password...

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is probably not the only solution, but I'd look at creating a USER table with a USER_ID and whatever columns are common to PERSON and COMPANY; then treat the PERSON table and the COMPANY table as extension tables of USER.  This solves several problems:

1) You can create a simple FK from the PASSWORD table to the USER table
2) You don't have to worry about somehow a COMPANY record and a PERSON record duplicating an ID value

Comment: yes but it is not good solution, what if I will have to add another kind of user type?

Comment: Actually it is a good solution - identical to the one in the answer you accepted, in fact.  But don't worry; if you want to insult the advice you're given I won't feel the need to offer advice to you again.

Comment: I didn't mean to insult anyone, your solution is good but I had question about it and I asked it. And thank you for your advice in really.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a pretty straight forward foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE person 
ADD CONSTRAINT person_fk FOREIGN KEY(id)
REFERENCES passowrd(user_id);

ALTER TABLE company
ADD CONSTRAINT company_fk FOREIGN KEY(id)
REFERENCES passowrd(user_id);
```

Comment: and then when I will search for password by Person Id, how will it know weather to find that Id in persons table or companies table?

Answer (score 0):

Add another table:

```
Entity
------
id
Entitytype [company/person]
ExternalID [either person.id or company.id]
```

Link Password.user_id to Entity.id

Comment: Hmmmm, I dont understan. Is it kind of datatype?

Comment: or I should crate another 2 tables?